# How do you call a delegate's function on a subclass in Swift?

Tags: swift, class, delegates, protocols, subclass

Class A is the delegate. 
Class B had a protocol with the methods, and I could call them simply by calling something like ***delegate?.myFunc()***

```
protocol ClassBDelegate: class {
    func myFunc()
}

class Class B {
    weak var delegate: ClassBDelegate?
    delegate?.myFunc()
}
```

But now ***myFunc()*** is in a another class (Class C) that Class A uses, but now I want Class B to call a function in Class A's instance of Class C.

How is that done? I know there's an answer, but maybe I don't know what to search for? I wish I could write something like ***delegate?.classC.myFunc()*** but it won't let me do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not class B's business to know anything about what its delegate *does* in order to fulfill its commands. That is the *point* of the protocol / delegate pattern. The protocol hides the implementation — more than that, the very *identity* — of the delegate.

It is class A, serving as the delegate, that will respond to `myFunc` by talking to its class C helper in some way. Maybe that is *its* delegate, I don't know. That doesn't matter. But don't change anything about class B's knowledge of the situation or the way it talks.

So, you need to write a function *in class A* that will call its class C for you. Class B should know nothing about what happens at the far end if class A is the delegate. That's a private implementation detail.

Comment: Oh okay. I'm trying to get away from writing more code in Class A, so it's a shame I have to write redundant functions in it just to call functions again in Class C.

Comment: I guess that's part of what stubs are for? The design doesn't really make sense to me. It's like I'm creating functions to call the same function.

Comment: Well, you are the one who brought class C into the story. So _obviously_ you have to change class A if you want to move the functionality from A into C. — I do not know what you mean about "stubs".

Comment: The "stubs" were required after I added the delegate to Class A's class declaration. Without them, I get an error forcing me to add them. More on mocks and stubs: https://www.andrewcbancroft.com/2014/07/15/how-to-create-mocks-and-stubs-in-swift/

Comment: That just means you declared that this class adopts the protocol but it didn't conform to it.

Comment: I don't really understand because it seems to.

Comment: Well, that is what the "stub" is for. That's the compiler actually putting in the code that you need in order to conform. However, it sounds like we may have moved on to another question at this point.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of a protocol is that it decouples you from having to specify a particular **class** that provides a service. Instead, you just specify that some object that conforms to the protocol provides the service.

You just need to make both your ClassA and ClassB objects have the same delegate. Then each one will call the delegate directly.

Comment: Is this different than matt's answer? Do you mean I need to make both my Class B and Class C objects have the same delegate?

Comment: In a way this is the same as what I said. But I didn't use the cool word "decouple"!

Comment: @matt, it sounds to me like the OP wants to be able to share a single instance of a delegate between two objects. That's unconventional, but there's nothing saying you can't do that. That's why I answered the way I did. I think that might be cleaner than having the ClassB object forward messages to it's delegate.

Comment: I don't disagree; I mentioned that as one possibility in my answer, when I said "Maybe that is _its_ delegate, I don't know".

Comment: The design is probably not even close to the best way, but I'll understand it more with experience. My main problem was that Class A was becoming way too large, and wanted to break it down into separate objects. I also wanted to have two different views recycle the use of that object. In this case, it's a label that removes itself after a set amount of time and also has some other functionality.